# datatable scrollX Horizontal not working

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have the following tables which is contains more than 10 columns.
I am using the datatables to show the data. I am using scroll horizontal because I have many columns. But the scroll not showing up. Please Help. Here is my screenshot for my table

[Scroll not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBGF9.png)

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>

    <th><center>Outlet ID</center></th>
    <th><center>Outlet Name</center></th>
    <th><center>Date</center></th>
    <th><center>Day</center></th>
    <th><center>Day Part</center></th>
    <th><center>Service</center></th>
    <th><center>Product</center></th>
    <th><center>Staff</center></th>
    <th><center>Pest</center></th>
    <th><center>Others</center></th>
    <th><center>Attentiveness</center></th>
    <th><center>Accuracy</center></th>
    <th><center>Speed</center></th>
    <th><center>Friendliness</center></th>
    <th><center>Food Handling & Hygiene</center></th>
    <th><center>Attentiveness</center></th>
    <th><center>Accuracy</center></th>
    <th><center>Speed</center></th>
    <th><center>Food</center></th>
    <th><center>Manpower</center></th>
    <th><center>Faulty Equipment</center></th>
    <th><center>Staff Behavior</center></th>
    <th><center>Restaurant Cleanliness</center></th>
    <th colspan=3><center>Action</center></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


     #code continue...

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my css and script for scroll

```
<style>
div.dataTables_wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "scrollY": 300,
    "scrollX": true
} );
} );
</script>
```

I need to show the horizontal scroll because I have more than 10 columns. Please Help. The result should show [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlGmu.png)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or snippet?

Answer (score 6):

make grid `responsible` and remove `with` CSS Style.

Column width can also be specified [ `width : "10%" or width:"100px"` ]

`<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">`

`<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0">`

Sharing my code sample

**CSHTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4>Customers</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table  table-striped table-hover" id="tblCustomers">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>CustomerId</th>     
                            <th>CustomerName</th>                          
                            <th>#</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS File**

```
   $('#tblCustomers').dataTable({
            "scrollX": true,        
            // other Options
            "columns": [
                { "data": "CustomerId", "title": "Customer Id", "width": "30px", "bSortable": false },
                { "data": "CustomerName", "title": "Name", "width": "250px", "bSortable": false }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<a data-customerid='" + row.CustomerId+ "' class='btn btn-primary customer-detail' href='#'>Detail</a>"
                    },
                    "targets": [2],
                    "class": "text-center",
                    "width": '70px'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just add `table-responsive` in class table.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

Change this:

```
</tbody>
</tables>
```

To this

```
</tbody>
</table>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o427uya0/1/)

Comment: Sorry, i miss spelling of my "tables". still not working.

Comment: check the fiddle

Comment: nicely done karolos. how to implement/merge it into my html ? I copy exactly of the js and css. still not showing up the horizontal scroll

Comment: The updated fiddle has your code inside 
then you must import these libraries to work

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`
`https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js`
`https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css`

Comment: I have included all the requirement libraries. If my <tbody> is empty, the table will work. If I fetch the data through my database, i will not show the scroll. How to make it working on dynamic data tables?

Comment: Check the answer, you have to initialize the table after the data are fetched or you can check the docs for how to dynamically add data to datatables

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": 300,
        "scrollX": true,
        "responsive": false

    } );
} );
```